# MySQL Sum two columns (1 -> n)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, left-join

I have a table 'rents' that has the field **ID** and a Foreign Key **events_id** and the field **total_value**, and i have another table 'payments' that has the field **ID**, a Foreign Key **rents_id** and the field **payment**.

**Table events:**

```
ID
```

**Table rents:**

```
ID,
total_value,
events_id
```

**Table payments:**

```
ID,
payment,
rents_id
```

There are many payments for the same ID of rents table, and there are many rents for the same ID of events table.
I need to create a query that shows the sum() for the field 'total_value' that has the same events ID in the rents table, and a sum() for the field 'payment' that has the same rents ID in the payments table.

I've managed to create this query that accomplish this task:

```
SELECT SUM(r.total_value) 'Total Value', (SELECT SUM(p.payment) FROM payments p INNER JOIN rents r ON p.rents_id = r.id WHERE r.events_id=8) 'Total Payment'
FROM rents r
WHERE r.events_id=8
;
```

I wonder if that's the only way to do that, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Please provide sample input and  especially output.

Comment: Asking for ways to do things or what is "best" without fully defining "best" & why you can't determine it yourself are not valid questions. [ask] [help]

Comment: i mean: performance + less code + good practice

Comment: Those are all themselves vague. And that comment doesn't address my last comment. Also please clarify via edits, not comments. And asking for lists of things is off-topic. Also this reflects no research on answering the question. Etc. [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a join - the idea is to compute intermediate payment sums in a subquery first, then join, and aggregate again in the outer query.

```
select sum(r.total_value) total_value, sum(p.payment) total_payment
from rents r
left join (
    select rents_id, sum(payment) payment from payments group by rents_id
) p on p.rents_id = r.id
where r.events_id = 8
```

The `left join` avoid filtering out rents that have no payment at all.

You can easily change the query to generate the result for all `event_id`s at once:

```
select r.events_id, sum(r.total_value) total_value, sum(p.payment) total_payment
from rents r
left join (
    select rents_id, sum(payment) payment from payments group by rents_id
) p on p.rents_id = r.id
group by r.events_id
```

Comment: This query is giving error 1054: Unknown Column 'p.payment' in 'field list'.
You are using a select clause instead of a table name after left join.

Comment: The sub-query alias was set to `r` .. I think you meant to set `p`

Comment: It continues to give the same error: unknown column 'p.payment' in field list. This is because the join is receiving a select clause instead of a table name.
In my query the INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN produces the same results, with null in total_payment column if there is no payments for that rent.

Comment: @Beto: I fixed the alias in the second query as well.

Comment: @GMB I know, i tested the second query as well and is giving error 1054: unknown column p.payment
I think there is no other way to show what i need besides the query i provided, i appreciate the help GMB.

Comment: @Beto: here is a db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a8603c5957563657e95bb55cae13139. With the table structures that you have provided in your question, you can see that none of the two queries errors. Likely, the structure of your tables is not exactly what you have showed, or you are not running the queries exactly as provided.

Comment: @GMB you're right! in db fiddle these queries are working, i populated the tables to see the results and is working as it should be: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e136c876afa2a658680a280e39c73fdc)
But in my MySQL Workbench with MySQL 8.0 is giving this error 1054, i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is probably the best approach (which I'll explain later).  However, you don't need a `join` in the subquery, just a correlation clause:

```
SELECT SUM(r.total_value) as Total_Value,
       (SELECT SUM(p.payment)
        FROM payments p 
        WHERE p.rents_id = r.id
--------------^ correlation clause that "links" the subquery to the outer query
       ) as Total_Payment
FROM rents r
WHERE r.events_id = 8;
```

Why is this the best approach?  First, with an index on `payments(rents_id)` and `rests(events_id)`, this should be the fastest method.

Second, note that the filtering condition is only included once in the query.  That makes it easy to update the query and less susceptible to error.

Third, this does not pre-aggregate the payments table.  Pre-aggregating either requires repeating the filtering condition (as in your version of the query) or aggregating more data than necessary (which affects performance).

In addition, I would advise you to *not* use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Gordon, this query is giving null for the total payment column, my query with inner join gives me 121.25 for the Total_Value  and 70.50 for the Total_Payment wich is the correct values for the two columns. I think the join clause is necessary in this situation.
But you have understand what i mean: performance + less code + good practice

Comment: @Beto . . . This would only give a `NULL` value if there is no payment that matches the  `r.id` in the outer query.  If that were the case, the `NULL` would return no value as well.

Comment: You query is giving null for Total_Payment, but there is payments for the rents where events_id=8
If i run my query the Total_Payment shows the correct value (sum of all payments made where r.events_id=8 and p.rents_id=r.id
I think there is no other way to show what i need besides the query i provided, i appreciate the help Gordon.